# Custom register_post_status not showing status label under project - WooCommerce Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, woocommerce

I have a custom post status for my WooCommerce products, and it works as it should. Only problem is when visiting a product in the backend I cannot see the status (although it is toggled on). Is there any way to make it show?

Edit: It does show in the drop-down menu, when previewing it (as seen in the image) the text does not show. So I can't see that it is chosen, as if it was published or a draft - that is the problem Im trying to solve!

Picture of the problem:

[image: No status text]

Here is my code:

```
register_post_status( 'custom-hide-product', array(
    'label'                     => _x( 'Slukket Produkt', 'post' ),
    'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Slukket Produkt <span class="count">(%s)</span>',  'Slukket Produkt (%s)', 'post' ),
    'public'                    => false,
    'exclude_from_search'       => true,
    'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
    'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
//     'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Slukket Produkt <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Slukket Produkt <span class="count">(%s)</span>' ),
) );

add_action( 'admin_footer', 'display_hide_status_option' );
function display_hide_status_option() {
    global $post;
    $complete = '';
    $label    = '';
    if ( $post->post_type === 'product' ) {
        if ( $post->post_status === 'custom-hide-product' ) {
            $selected = 'selected';
        }
        echo '<script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                    $("select#post_status").append("<option value=\"custom-hide-product\" ' . $complete . '>Slukket Produkt</option>");
                    $(".misc-pub-section label").append("' . $label . '");
                });
              </script>
        ';
    }
}
```

I hope someone can guide me in the right direction - the Dev WP page didnt help me!